# testing controller action which returns RedirectToRouteResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in my controller:

```
RedirectToRouteResult Create(UserDTO UserDTO)
```

Which at some point decides with which HTML to respond after a post request by redirecting to an action:

```
return ModelState.IsValid ? RedirectToAction("ThanksCreate") : RedirectToAction("Register");
```

In my unit tests I would like to get hold of the ‘views’ modelstate somehow like this:

```
var modelState = result.ViewData.ModelState;

Assert.IsFalse( modelState.IsValid );
```

where ‘result’ (ViewResult) is the result of the action ‘Create’ depending on the submitted DTO. My dilemma is that my action ‘returns’ a RedirectToRouteResult which I thought is quite nice but it might not be testable or is it?

How could I get hold of the ModelState in my scenario? Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Why would you need to go through `ViewData`?  Since this is a unit test, wouldn't you set up your DTO to either have valid data or invalid data and then verify that it redirects to the correct action for each one?

Comment: That's what I want to do but more fine grained. I want to check whether certain key/errormessage combinations are set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866137/testing-the-controller-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer on your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866137/testing-the-controller-in-asp-net-mvc) (related) question.  In this scenario, I think it's arguably incorrect to test the model state as it isn't exposed outside the method.  Rather, you should use your set up to induce correct/incorrect model state and test that the method has the proper output based on the given set up.